# sencha studio: configuration of archive server

Tags: javascript, testing, extjs, archive

How should I configure Archive Server in Sencha Studio?

[Configure Remote Archive Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJCAh.png)

I tried direct it on folder "mystoragearea" with storage.jason containing sample storage area

```
{
    "my_secret_key": {
        "path": "/mystoragearea"
    }
}
```

But only what I get is

> Failed to load remote archive catalog : path/to/mystoragearea/catalog.json

Answer (score 1):

You asked 3months ago, but - for future generations!

[Sencha Tests Doc](http://docs.sencha.com/sencha_test/guides/command_line_archive_server.html#command_line_archive_server_-_starting_the_archive_server) - Sencha has good tutorial how set up your Archive server and then run test, save it.

Default port is `1903`, so 
**Archive Server:** `http://localhost:1903` 
**Archive Root Folder:** path from storage.json - something like `/results`